# Scala macros. Use string in quasiquotes

Tags: scala, scala-macros, scala-quasiquotes

I'm trying to generate statement by case class parameters.

```
case class f(a:String, b:String){
  val statement = Macroses.st[f]
}

object MacrosTest {
  def start() {
    val result =  f("1", "2").statement
  }
}
```

Result must be INSERT INTO tableName(a, b) VALUES ('1', '2');

This is my macros

```
 def st[T]:Insert = macro st_impl[T]

 def st_impl[A : c.WeakTypeTag](c: Context): c.Expr[Insert] = {
   import c.universe._
   val methods: List[String] = c.weakTypeOf[A].typeSymbol.
   typeSignature.decls.toList.filterNot(_.isMethod)
   .map(_.name.toString)
   c.Expr[Insert](q"""QueryBuilder.insertInto("tableName")${methods.map(v => s""".value("$v", $v)""").mkString}""")
 }
```

I got exception:

```
 c.universe.Name expected but c.universe.Tree found
```

If i use this quasiquote it works good.

```
(q"""QueryBuilder.insertInto("tableName").value("a", a).value("b", b)""")
```

Comment: In quasiquotes, $ doesn't mean interpolating a string like what s"" does. It has to be a tree.  Let me think a bit.

Comment: I did so:

`q"""
         import com.datastax.driver.core.querybuilder.QueryBuilder
          ${methods.map(v =>(v.toColumnCase, TermName(v)))}
          .foldLeft(QueryBuilder.insertInto(${reify(tableName.splice)}))((newInsert, next)
         =>   newInsert.value(next._1, next._2)
         )"""` but foldLeft works in runtime and it's doesn't i want.